# Growth rate of primitive recursive functions

Tags: recursion, recursive

Pardon me for asking a question whose answer is surely well-known, but
is beyond my expertise:

> ***Q***. Is the growth rate of each [primitive recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) $f(n)$ bounded by some exponential $O(c^n)$, or $O(n^n)$, or ...?

I know [Ackermann's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) grows faster than exponential, but it is not primitive recursive.

Comment: I am also not an expert but I am pretty sure that towers of exponents, and maybe even $2\uparrow^k n$ for any constant $k$ are primitive recursive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation.

Comment: Actually, after googling something on a hunch, it [seems](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hsxDiWvVdBcC&lpg=PA332&pg=PA332#v=onepage&q&f=false) that for every primitive recursive function $f(n)$ there exists a constant $k$ such that $f(n) \le A(n,k)$, where $A$ the Ackermann function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is no, there is no exponential bound on PR.
PR contains [Knuth's up-arrow functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY), etc.
PR is equal to the union of [Grzegorczyk hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grzegorczyk_hierarchy).
Exponential functions appear at the third level of the Grzegorczyk hierarchy.

PR can alternatively be defined using the iteration function in place of recursion.

A good reference for information about these classes is the first chapter of second volume of "[Classical Recursion Theory](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Z97uAAAAMAAJ)".

Also have the general function growth hierarchies like 
[Grzegorczyk hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grzegorczyk_hierarchy),
[slow-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-growing_hierarchy), and
[fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy).